# How to make use of an if in mysql within a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a stored procedure and I am validating that when the id_plan is greater than zero, that is, it does the query taking into account the id_plan, otherwise ignore it and make the query by skipping the id_plan

This is how I am doing the query

```
SET @id_convenio = 64; 
SET @id_plan = 20;
SET @fecha_ini = "03/01/2019";
SET @fecha_fin = "05/08/2019 23:59:59";

SELECT PD.id_detalle_precio, P.id_admision, P.id_paciente, HC.id_hc, 0 AS ind_revisado, 0 AS ind_borrado, NULL AS num_factura, P.id_convenio,
P.id_plan, NULL AS cod_prestador, TD.codigo_detalle AS tipo_documento, PA.numero_documento, 
DATE_FORMAT(IFNULL(HC.fecha_hora_hc, P.fecha_pago), '%d/%m/%Y') AS fecha_consulta_t, IFNULL(PD.num_autorizacion, A.num_autorizacion) AS num_autorizacion, PD.cod_procedimiento, 
NULL AS fin_consulta, NULL AS causa_ext, NULL AS cod_ciex_prin, NULL AS cod_ciex_rel1, NULL AS cod_ciex_rel2, NULL AS cod_ciex_rel3, NULL AS tipo_diag_prin, 
0 AS valor_consulta, 0 AS valor_cuota, 0 AS valor_neto, NULL AS observaciones, 1 AS id_usuario_crea, NOW() AS fecha_crea

FROM pagos P 

INNER JOIN pagos_detalle PD ON P.id_pago=PD.id_pago 
INNER JOIN planes PL ON P.id_plan=PL.id_plan 
INNER JOIN maestro_procedimientos MP ON PD.cod_procedimiento=MP.cod_procedimiento 
INNER JOIN pacientes PA ON P.id_paciente=PA.id_paciente 
LEFT JOIN listas_detalle TD ON PA.id_tipo_documento=TD.id_detalle 
INNER JOIN admisiones A ON P.id_admision=A.id_admision 
INNER JOIN tipos_citas_det CD ON A.id_tipo_cita=CD.id_tipo_cita 
INNER JOIN historia_clinica HC ON P.id_admision=HC.id_admision 
AND CD.id_tipo_reg=HC.id_tipo_reg 
WHERE P.id_convenio=@id_convenio 
/**AND P.id_plan=@id_plan**/
AND IF @id_plan>0 THEN  P.id_plan=@id_plan
END IF
AND P.estado_pago=2 
AND HC.fecha_hora_hc BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_ini, '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE(@fecha_fin, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') 
AND MP.tipo_procedimiento='C' 
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT RC.id_detalle_precio 
FROM rips_consultas RC 
WHERE RC.id_convenio=@id_convenio AND RC.id_plan=@id_plan AND PD.id_detalle_precio=RC.id_detalle_precio);
```

This is the error that shows me

5 queries executed, 4 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query: SELECT PD.id_detalle_precio, P.id_admision, P.id_paciente, HC.id_hc, 0 AS ind_revisado, 0 AS ind_borrado, NULL AS num_factura, P...

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@id_plan THEN set P.id_plan=@id_plan
END IF
AND P.estado_pago=2 
AND HC.fecha_ho' at line 18

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part

```
WHERE P.id_convenio=@id_convenio 
AND IF @id_plan>0 THEN  P.id_plan=@id_plan
END IF
AND P.estado_pago=2
...
```

can be expressed in multiple ways.

Using the IF() function:

```
WHERE P.id_convenio=@id_convenio 
AND IF(@id_plan>0, P.id_plan=@id_plan, TRUE)
AND P.estado_pago=2
...
```

Using a CASE statement

```
WHERE P.id_convenio=@id_convenio 
AND CASE WHEN @id_plan>0 THEN  P.id_plan=@id_plan ELSE TRUE END
AND P.estado_pago=2
...
```

Using an OR condition:

```
WHERE P.id_convenio=@id_convenio 
AND (NOT (@id_plan>0) OR  P.id_plan=@id_plan)
AND P.estado_pago=2
...
```

which is equivalent to

```
WHERE P.id_convenio=@id_convenio 
AND (@id_plan<=0 OR  P.id_plan=@id_plan)
AND P.estado_pago=2
...
```

If `@id_plan` can be `NULL`, then you might need

```
WHERE P.id_convenio=@id_convenio 
AND (@id_plan<=0 OR @id_plan is NULL OR P.id_plan=@id_plan)
AND P.estado_pago=2
...
```

If `@id_plan` can neither be `NULL` or negative, then you just need

```
WHERE P.id_convenio=@id_convenio 
AND (@id_plan=0 OR P.id_plan=@id_plan)
AND P.estado_pago=2
...
```

Comment: thanks bro, you are a genious